# How do i get this program to work as expected?

Tags: c

The value of winningNum(random value) does not change in this.How do i get it to change after each iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
int guess;
int guess_count = 0;
int guess_limit = 10;


do {
  int winningNum = rand() % 50 + 1;
  
   printf("Enter your guess (number between 1 and 50): ");
   scanf("%d", &guess);
   guess_count++;
   if (guess > winningNum){
    printf("Too High... \n");
   }
   else if(guess < winningNum){
    printf("Too Low...\n");
   }
   if(guess == winningNum){
    printf("Correct,the number was %d. \n", winningNum);
    break;
   }

  }while(guess_count < guess_limit);
   if(guess_count == guess_limit){
    printf("You made %d wrong guesses.",guess_count);
   }
}
```

I tried using the do-while loop, but nothing changed. I expect winningNum's (random value) value to change after each iteration.

Comment: I assume the problem is that the target number `winningNum` is changing after every guess and you do not want it to so folks have a chance at guessing it. The fix would be to move `int winningNum = rand() % 50 + 1;` outside the loop. If the problem is that the initial number is the same every time you need to call `srand` with a seed that changes on every run.

Comment: Thank you, I just fixed it using srand()

Comment: You're confusing the word "iteration" with "invocation".  Each time a loop body is executed is an iteration.  Each time a program is run is an invocation.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just loop `while(guess_count < guess_limit) { .. }` and then handle the win/lose with `if (guess_count < guess_limit) { puts ("you win"); } else { printf("You made %d wrong guesses.",guess_count); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `srand()` to set the seed for the psudo-random generator.  It's a good idea to do this once in the start of `main()`.

Here are some other suggestions:

1. Formatting matters for readability (`int guess;` and later should indented).
2. Minimize scope of variables (move `guess` to just before the `scanf()`).
3. Prefer using a symbolic constant, say, `#define GUESS_LIMIT 10` to a regular variable (or at least make the variable a `const`).
4. Check return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.
5. `if(guess == winningNum){` breaks with the pattern you use earlier; prefer a simple `else {`.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by click the check mark next to it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It was of help.